# extract variable items on single line using grep

Tags: perl, grep

I want to extract all date-time from files,

The content in my `tmp.txt`:

```
2020-10-17 16:04:08.590 [Thread-173] INFO  c.g.c.jobhandler.service.: "1600704240\\\\"2020-10-17 16:03:43\\\"-\
2020-10-17 16:05:03.780 [Thread-173] INFO  c.g.c.jobhandler.service.:"2020-10-17 16:05:43\\\"-\2020-10-17 16:05:57
```

This is my command:

```sh
grep -oP '\d*-\d*-\d* \d*:\d*:\d*' tmp.txt > res.txt
```

The result of my command

```
2020-10-17 16:04:08
2020-10-17 16:03:43
2020-10-17 16:05:03
2020-10-17 16:05:43
2020-10-17 16:05:57
```

I want the extracted date-time items also output in a single line as it's the position in the original file:

```
2020-10-17 16:04:08 2020-10-17 16:03:43
2020-10-17 16:05:03 2020-10-17 16:05:43 2020-10-17 16:05:57
```

How I can get this result. Thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple with Perl:

```
$ perl -nE 'say join " ", /(\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)/g' tmp.txt 
2020-10-17 16:04:08 2020-10-17 16:03:43
2020-10-17 16:05:03 2020-10-17 16:05:43 2020-10-17 16:05:57
```

- `-n`: run the code for every line in the input
- `-E`: execute the code using all current Perl features (specifically, here I'm using `say()`)
- `say`: display a string followed by a newline
- `join " "`: join together the following list using a space between each element
- `/.../`: match this pattern
- `/.../g`: match all occurrences of this pattern
- `/(...)/`: capture (and return in a list) everything that matches the regex
- `\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+`: regex to match a date